# How do I create a raster file from a geopandas dataframe storing lats, longs, values, and geometries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapely, fiona, pandas

From a text file with time, lat, long, and cf values, I create a pandas dataframe (`cf_df`). Then I use the lat, long values to create a geoseries and create a geopandas dataframe from the original pandas dataframe and the geoseries:

```py
#creating geometries
geometry = [geom.Point(xy) for xy in zip(cf_df['long'], cf_df['lat'])]

# creating geodataframe with original cf and new geometries
geo_cf_df = GeoDataFrame(cf_df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```

Ending up with a geopandas dataframe like this:

```py
        time    lat    long   cf              geometry
0          1  15.25  200.25  NaN  POINT (200.25 15.25)
1          1  15.25  200.75  NaN  POINT (200.75 15.25)
2          1  15.25  201.25  NaN  POINT (201.25 15.25)
3          1  15.25  201.75  NaN  POINT (201.75 15.25)
4          1  15.25  202.25  NaN  POINT (202.25 15.25)
5          1  15.25  202.75  NaN  POINT (202.75 15.25)
6          1  15.25  203.25  NaN  POINT (203.25 15.25)
7          1  15.25  203.75  NaN  POINT (203.75 15.25)
8          1  15.25  204.25  NaN  POINT (204.25 15.25)
9          1  15.25  204.75  NaN  POINT (204.75 15.25)
10         1  15.25  205.25  NaN  POINT (205.25 15.25)
...      ...    ...     ...  ...                   ...
```

What methods are available for creating a ASCII-based raster that could be imported to ArcMap?

Comment: Are you sure it is a pandas dataframe and not a geopandas [geodataframe](http://geopandas.org/user.html#geodataframe)?

Comment: You are right - I create a geoseries of points by extracting the lat,long values from the pandas dataframe, and then merge this object with the original dataframe into a geopandas dataframe. See the edited question.

Comment: Are the points regularly spaced or do they have differing distances between them?

Comment: The points are regularly spaced in the coordinate system. In one instance they are in a geographic coordinate system, WGS 84, and another data set I'm working with they are in a projected coordinate system. I don't mix the points from the two different systems, I just need to deal with each separately.

Comment: I've started working on this in R, and it seems that i will get there soon, but I still want to know how to do this in Python.

Comment: If they are regularly spaced you can create an [ESRI ASCII Raster](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm) by manually creating the header, which only requires the number of rows, cols, corner coordinates and cell size. You could to that in Python but it should be easier and quicker in a text editor.